# What is the difference between a logical and/or and a bit-wise and/or?

Tags: bit-manipulation, verilog, logical-operators

Assume `a= 4'b1110, b= 4'b0010`

What is the difference between A && B and A & B and what is the difference between A ||B and A | B? What is the result of each of them and how is it done?

I tried reading some of the questions/answers on SO but I couldn't find any definitive answers.

Comment: one is bit operation, one is logic. one yields a sequence of bits in different integer data type, one yields boolean definitely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`logical` deals purely with the true/false values. The component bits are irrelevant, there's just all-zeroes (false), and not-all-zeroes (true).

`bitwise` does exactly as the name suggests - it considers individual bits.

```
a = 42    00101010
b = 23    00010111
c = 0     00000000

a || b -> true       a && b -> true
a | b  -> 63         a & b  -> 2
a || c -> true       a && c -> false
a | c  -> 42         a & c  -> 0
```

In more detail:

```
a || b ->    00101010
          || 00010111
          -----------
             00111111 -> 63, which is non-zero, therefore -> TRUE
```

`a | b` is exactly the same, but since it's only dealing with the bits, the calculation stops at `63`.

```
a && b ->    00101010
          && 00010111
          -----------
             00000010 -> 2 -> non-zero, therefore -> TRUE
```

If we add in `d = 21`:

```
a && d -> 42 && 21 ->      00101010
                        && 00010101
                        -----------
                           00000000 -> all-zeroes, therefore false
```

Comment: Can you give an example as to when the result of a logical operation will be all zeroes?

Comment: As this is Verilog, it is also important to note that the logical operators will produce a result that is 1-bit in length (ie, either `1'b1` or `1'b0`) while bitwise operators will produce a result that is the the same as the length of the longest argument (ie, `2'b10 && 3'b010` will result in `3'b010`)

Comment: @MarcB `42 && 21` returns TRUE, not FALSE. Tested with 5 different simulators on [edaplayground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/P7p).

Comment: @Greg: guess it tests non-false && non-false, then, instead of doing bit-wise and and casting the result to boolean.

Answer (score 1):

It is done by creating a Verilog testbench and running a simulation:

```
module tb;

reg [3:0] a, b;
initial begin
    a= 4'b1110;
    b= 4'b0010;
    $display("a&b  = 'b%b", a&b);
    $display("a&&b = 'b%b", a&&b);
    $display("a|b  = 'b%b", a|b);
    $display("a||b = 'b%b", a||b);
    #5 $finish;
end

endmodule
```

Output:

```
a&b  = 'b0010
a&&b = 'b1
a|b  = 'b1110
a||b = 'b1
```

Refer to the IEEE Std 1800-2012 for more details about Verilog operators.